# Put Python app on a remote server

Tags: python, apache, web-applications

I'm trying to put my project to our school page. I have used Flask framework to make a web application which runs on my local host. To run it on the web, I was recommended to put all files from project to my school folder `www.xxx.com/projects/myproject` into the folder `public_html` from which **Apache** server should read the files. I did *copy+paste* all files from my project to myproject folder. Now, when I try to run it on the remote school computer it seems to work correctly - when I run app.py it returns `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/`. But then I check the page where should be rendered html page, it shows only the project files, no html.

What should I do to make it work?

PS: I'm trying to check the page via Internet.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import render_template
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import S
import B

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('my-form.html')

def setup():
    global b
    b = B.B()


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def search():

    pattern = request.form['text']

    startTime = time()

    arr = []

    s = S.S(pattern,b)
    res = s.getR()

    for k in res:
        t = b.find(k)
        for key in t.keys():
            string = str(key)
            arr.append(string.decode('utf-8'))

    return render_template('my-form.html', arr=arr, pattern=pattern)

app.debug=False
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
    app.run()
```

PS: I have no index.html anywhere, I suppose, that it should render 'my-form.html' and show it.

Comment: You should really start with some documentation on how to deploy a Python application (start searching with "`wsgi`"). Apache isn't executing your application at all right now, it's merely serving files (because it's a file server). You need to either configure Apache to use `mod_wsgi` to execute your app, or to proxy incoming traffic to your app (of course, you could use another webserver altogether for that). Alternatively, you could expose your app directly on the internet (bind to `"0.0.0.0"` instead of `"127.0.0.1"`, bypassing Apache altogether (but I wouldn't recommend that).

Answer (score 0):

On your school's server (Support for python):

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi`

also you must check permissions for your files in public_html.

problems maybe is a missing content type in header HTTP

"Content-Type: text/html\n\n"